# How to import a package from another package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, package

I have a Java desktop application written in IntelliJ.
Under src folder i have 2 packages:

```
main -> Java -> com -> Class A

test -> Java -> demo -> Class B
```

How do I make class A recognize class B?

When I write import test.* IntelliJ doesn't recognize the folder / package called test.

Comment: `src/main/java` should be for source code and `src/test/java` should be for test related code... You shouldn't really be importing code used for testing into the source packages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import the last package that contains your classes.

```
import test.java.demo.*;
```

Comment: Presumably `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are content roots. There won't be a `test.java.demo` package.

Answer (score 0):

If the demo package is not dedicated for test you can copy the folder to the main/java folder. Indeed main / java has no visibility for test / java. However test / java has visibility to main / java.